# Why cant I use `#include` after upgrading my driver

Tags: opengl, glsl

After updating my graphics driver and trying to run [this](http://john-chapman-graphics.blogspot.al/2013/02/pseudo-lens-flare.html) example from John Chapman's blog I got this error

```
Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:8: error(#105) #version must occur before any other program statement
```

The way that the version is defined is by including a file containing this code

```
#ifndef DEF_GLSL_
#define DEF_GLSL_

#version 420

...
```

So inside all other shader files one can see that the first line is as follows

```
#include "common/def.glsl"
...
```

I remember this working perfectly a few months ago. So what exactly has changed and the `#include` command is no longer valid?

Comment: There are a lot of code snippets on the linked page, but none of them appear to have the character "`#`". Could you show a minimal example of code that you know gives this error message?

Comment: @trichoplax my bad. I should have explained that there is an executable provided in order for you to run it. I will update the question with a minimal example.

Answer (score 4):

The error message gives a clue in the wording:

```
#version must occur before any other program statement
```

Is there a reason that the previous 2 lines need to appear before the `#version` line? If not, you can avoid the error by moving this line to the beginning, since the actions of the lines are independent of their order in this instance.

The `#version` needing to be at the beginning of the file is not a new requirement. I don't know why you were able to run this code previously.

Comment: Yet as you can see by yourself Chapman's unedited algorithm is given in this exact form, and I do guarantee that it could run perfectly on this but also another computer (both having ATI graphics cards). I think it could have something to do with Vulkan and a more strict set of rules, but I have not been able to verify it yet.

Comment: @green_leaf oh yes I'm not doubting that it did work - I just don't have an explanation for why. I guess the change was a "correction" even though it hasn't turned out to be helpful for you...

Comment: that's very classic with ATI

Comment: @v.oddou indeed now that you mention it. It seems that they do that quite often.